# Sql in Visual Basic returning nothing while same query in Access returns right value

Tags: sql, vb.net

My code:

```
strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=PIZZA.accdb"
strSql = "SELECT INGREDIENTNR AS NR FROM INGREDIENTS WHERE DESCRIPTION = '" & ingredients(counter * 2) & "'"

objConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
objCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSql, objConnection)

objConnection.Open()
objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

Dim strIngNr As String = objDataReader("NR")
```

`Dim strIngNr As String = objDataReader("NR")` gives the error: `No data exists for the row/column.`
But the same query in Access does return `14`, which is the right value and what I want to get. What am I doing wrong?

Another thing: `counter` is the right value, tested that already.
And another thing: `DESCRIPTION` is a String

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `while objDataReader.Read` with' `If objDataReader.HasRows`? Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 If this returns 1 column & 1 row output, use `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Thank you, it is resolved now.

Comment: You should really be using parameterised SQL rather than concatenating strings.  If whatever description is has a `'` in it, it will break this SQL statement.  Also, more importantly, security and such.

Comment: @Siyual This is how we learned it at school... I don't know any other ways to do this, so I just use what I've learned.

Comment: Truly unfortunate.  This usually IS the method taught in schools, but it is also wide open to security issues.  @ikhebgeenaccount, if you are interested in security, look up "SQL Injection", as this is a major problem with in-line SQL such as this.